# Understanding the Architecture of Magento module

Tags: php, magento

I was working with PHP Core and custom MVCs by 1 and half years until when moved to magento desk.

I find it very difficult first, but later got grip in Theme integration and maintenance of previously done modules. Now I got in to Module creation and really confused with the architecture.

In frank, Everytime when I write a new code, It works well, but later edited out wasting so much time of seniors since It does not met completely with Magento's coding style.

For an example, when I need to check something and update a database, I writes,

```
<?php 
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = "SELECT ststus FROM table WHERE Id='".$id."'";
$select_query = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
$update_value= $select_query[0];
if($update_value=='2')
{
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "UPDATE table SET field_name='C' WHERE Id='".$id."'";
$writeConnection->query($query);
}
?>
```

This is later changed to simply this,

```
foreach ($dealroomIds as $dealroomId) {
                $manufacturers = Mage::getSingleton('module/module')
                    ->load($dealroomId)
                    ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status')); //getting status 
                    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('status')=='2'){
                    $manufacturers->setRunningStatus('C'); // setting new status
                    }
                $manufacturers->setIsMassupdate(true)
                    ->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('dealroom/deals')->UpdateDealProducts($dealroomId); // Update
                    }
```

The above given is just an example and nothing more than that.

To know more about the coding style and standard, I think is neccessory to know more about

- Block
- controllers
- Model
- Helper
- Data

I searched but whatever I read and understand is just far away from the basic. If anyone point out the connections and functions of these in simple and basic, it will be helpful to me.

Comment: You know about the Tutorials on magentocommerce.com? If that doesn't help, what exactly are you looking at?

Comment: Per your example, quit trying to write SQL code, Magento uses collections and hides the horribly complex EAV database queries behind far more understandable OOP interactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check this? There are total 8 articles by Alan Storm to cover most part of Magento.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

If you are finding it difficult to understand, I'm afraid to say, you need to strengthen your OOPs and MVC concepts first.